# Downloading hibernate jar files

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to download hibernate [hopefully version 3]  from http://www.hibernate.org/hibernate/downloads and for last two days I am getting either 404 or 500 from a proxy server some how. It appears that visiting above url spawns a prox server request to somewhere else. I have tried this from different IPs, from remote locations but this refuses to work.

On the other hand I downloaded the source from sourceforge and then tried to compile, which again did not worked for some other reason. I could not find compiled hibernate 3 on sourceforge.

So My question is : Is there some other reliable source of hibernate ?
Does [the link](http://www.hibernate.org/hibernate/downloads) work for you guys.

Comment: Have you tried downloading From [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.hibernate|hibernate-core|3.6.10.Final|jar) ? Produces following link [download](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.10.Final/hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may download jars in maven repository.
Here is the link:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core

Comment: Thanks I think it will work , though I find that now with this method I will have to get individual jar(s) ... separately. But that should work for now.

Answer (score 3):

I download my hibernate jar files from this address [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/) It has version 2,3 and 4.check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download hibernate from here. It is a download with dependencies. This is maybe better than the single core file: https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=hibernate-core&g=org.hibernate&v=5.2.0.Final&downloadable=1